# ELIFECYCLE Error using Python-Shell and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell, memory

I've seen similar questions to this but have a more specific ask related to the ELIFECYCLE error. Specifically, I'm using python-shell with NodeJS, and am able to successfully call my python script, print a small array, and interpret it on the js side. However, when I increase the size of the array in the python script that's being sent to my server, I receive the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Although the PythonShell works to an extent, the code is paraphrased as follows:

```
var pyshell = new PythonShell(scriptSource,options);
pyshell.send(req.body.itema);
pyshell.on('message',function(message){
res.send(message);
return;
});
pyshell.end(function(err,code,signal...etc
```

Other answers indicate this may be due to a RAM/memory issue, I've tried increasing my size on start via the following:

```
     "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4076 server.js"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can handle the larger data transfer? I'd appreciate any thoughts - happy to provide more detail.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post an example pythons script so that I can try to reproduce it my machine.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - the array would definitely be too big to post here (it's a couple thousand lines). But the python script only has two lines - first sets the array variable (dataA = [....]) and the second line is print(dataA)